# How would I check if each cell of an array has neighbors of a specified value quickly in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have an array like

```py
    np.array([[0,0,0,1,0],
               [0,0,0,0,0],
               [0,1,0,0,0],
               [0,0,0,1,0],
               [0,0,0,0,0]],dtype=bool)
```

and I want to have a boolean array of all values with a neighboring cell that isn't 0 in that array, like:

```py
    np.array([[0,0,1,0,1],
               [1,1,1,1,1],
               [1,0,1,1,1],
               [1,1,1,0,1],
               [0,0,1,1,1]],dtype=bool)
```

How would I do this without looping over everything in a python loop (since that's really slow)?

Comment: Consider using a *convolution*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a sliding window to take maximum value in that window.

```
def foo(arr, window):
    r, c = arr.shape
    wr, wc = window
    ans = arr * 0
    for i in range(r):
        for j in range(c):
            if not arr[i, j]:                
                ans[i, j] = arr[max(i - wr, 0):min(i + wr + 1, r), max(j - wc, 0):min(j + wc + 1, c)].max()
            else:
                ans[i, j] = 0
        
    return ans

data = np.array([[0,0,0,1,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,1,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,1,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0]])
foo(data, [1, 1])
# array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
#        [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

OR

```
from scipy.ndimage import maximum_filter

ans = maximum_filter(data, size=(3, 3))
ans[data == 1] = 0
ans
# array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
#        [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use `numpy`, my way is to find out the neighbors of all true values in the original array, the calculation method is to judge whether the Chebyshev distance (L-infinite distance) between the position of elements in the array and the position of true values is 1, then merge them with logical or operation:

```
>>> ar = np.array([[0,0,0,1,0],
... [0,0,0,0,0],
... [0,1,0,0,0],
... [0,0,0,1,0],
... [0,0,0,0,0]], bool)
>>> row, col = ar.nonzero()
>>> rows, cols = np.indices(ar.shape)
>>> np.any([np.maximum(np.abs(rows - i), np.abs(cols - j)) == 1 for i, j in zip(row, col)], 0)
array([[False, False,  True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True]])
```

By broadcasting, you can also avoid the list comprehension:

```
>>> rows, cols = np.indices(ar.shape, sparse=True)  # Setting to sparse does not affect the calculation.
>>> i = np.abs(rows[None] - row[:, None, None])
>>> j = np.abs(cols[None] - col[:, None, None])
>>> (np.maximum(i, j) == 1).any(0)
array([[False, False,  True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True]])
```

To make the code look shorter, I used `None` instead of `np.newaxis`, you can use the latter for readability.

After testing, even with the help of broadcasting, it is slower than the second answer of @d.b , but it is not too bad:

```
>>> def loop_reduce(ar):
...     row, col = ar.nonzero()
...     rows, cols = np.indices(ar.shape)
...     return np.any([np.maximum(np.abs(rows - i), np.abs(cols - j)) == 1 for i, j in zip(row, col)], 0)
...
>>> def broadcast_reduce(ar):
...     row, col = ar.nonzero()
...     rows, cols = np.indices(ar.shape, sparse=True)
...     i = np.abs(rows[None] - row[:, None, None])
...     j = np.abs(cols[None] - col[:, None, None])
...     return (np.maximum(i, j) == 1).any(0)
...
>>> def max_filter(ar):
...     ans = maximum_filter(ar, size=(3, 3))
...     ans[ar] = False
...     return ans
...
>>> timeit(lambda: loop_reduce(ar), number=10000)
0.3127206000208389
>>> timeit(lambda: broadcast_reduce(ar), number=10000)
0.13910009997198358
>>> timeit(lambda: max_filter(ar), number=10000)
0.12893440001062118
```

At least this can be a way for you to solve similar problems in the future :-)